# jQuery ajax request and inline javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello fellow Stackoverflow users,

I have a page which does a AJAX request to update the shoppingcart.
The problem is that the cart has some inline javascript which breaks the page on the ajax request.

The following is the ajax request i use:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "Default.aspx?ID=5&productid=PROD147&cartcmd=add",
        success: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Default.aspx?ID=5",
                dataType: "html",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $(html).remove('script');
                    console.log(html);
                    var ajax_shoppingcart = $('#shoppingcart',html).html(); 
                    $('#shoppingcart').html(ajax_shoppingcart);
                    var ajax_basket = $('#topbanner_eshop',html).filter(":not(script)").html(); 
                    $('#topbanner_eshop').html(ajax_basket);
                  }
            });
        }
    });
```

But the problem is that the data it loads into #topbanner_eshop contains some inline javascript, which breaks the page.

It tries to import the following html:

```
<div id="topbanner_eshop">
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="Default.aspx?ID=24">Shop videre » </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            2 varer i kurven
        </div>
        <div>
            Total
        </div>
        <div>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
            // var str="190,00"; 
            var str="DKK 190,00"; 
            document.write(str.replace(/,00/, ",-")); 
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when it reaches the inline script it replaces the whole page with the script result.

What did i do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by 'inline javascript breaks the page'? Also calling `document.write()` after the page has been loaded will overwrite the entire page. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one thing, there's this:

```
 $(html).remove('script');
```

You're explicitly removing the script elements.

Then, the actual script uses "document.write()", which, once the containing page has been loaded, will implicitly destroy it.  In other words, calling "document.write()" implicitly calls "document.open()", which, in turn, erases the DOM.

Instead of "document.write()", you could do this:

```
<span id='amount'></span>
<script>
  var str = "DKK 190,00"; // I presume that's actually a server-side thing
  $('#amount').text(str.replace(/,00/, ',-'));
</script>
```

It would be a lot better to just fix the string with server-side code.

Comment: Thanks.. Ill try it and come back. As you might have noticed i didnt write the basket code. And im a little unclear on regular JS.. But how can they execute it on the regular page load(it works fine if you visit the page instead of using ajax), without it erasing the page?

Comment: Because while a complete page is in the process of being interpreted, it's still "open", so a call to "document.write()" does not re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is functioning properly. The problem is with the HTML code. Calling `document.write` on any page will replace the entire contents of the page with the result, so you probably want to use something else.